# Practical solver for convex QCQP?

Tags: optimization, cplex, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am working with a convex QCQP as the following:

```
Min e'Ie
z'Iz=n
[some linear equalities and inequalities that contain variables w,z, and e]
w>=0, z in [0,1]^n
```

So the problem has only one quadratic constraint, except the objective, and some variables are nonnegative. The matrices of both quadratic forms are identity matrices, thus are positive definite.

I can move the quadratic constraint to the objective but it must have the negative sign so the problem will be nonconvex:

```
min e'Ie-z'Iz
```

The size of the problem can be up to 10000 linear constraints, with 100 nonnegative variables and almost the same number of other variables.

The problem can be rewritten as an MIQP as well, as z_i can be binary, and z'Iz=n can be removed.
So far, I have been working with CPLEX via AIMMS for MIQP and it is very slow for this problem. Using the QCQP version of the problem with CPLEX, MINOS, SNOPT and CONOPT is hopeless as they either cannot find a solution, or the solution is not even close to an approximation that I know a priori.

Now I have three questions:

1. Do you know any method/technique to get rid of the quadratic constraint as this form without going to MIQP?
2. Is there any "good" solver for this QCQP? by good, I mean a solver that efficiently finds the global optimum in a resonable time.
3. Do you think using SDP relaxation can be a solution to this problem? I have never solved an SDP problem in reallity, so I do not know how efficient SDP version can be. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless there is significant structure in the model, which you understand how to exploit in an SDP setting using state-of-the-art theory on symmetry reductions etc, an SDP approach will not get you any further. The MIQP form is what you will have to work with. If neither cplex, gurobi or mosek manages to solve this in time acceptable to you, you will have build you own solver trying to exploit problem structure (heuristics, cuts, etc) and hope you've found something clever. MIQPs are intractable in general so it might just be that you cannot solve it.

Comment: Quadratic equality constraints lead to non-convex problems.  See and earlier [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112348/trying-to-read-quadratic-program-in-cplex-get-error/10112564#10112564).

Comment: Thanks @DavidNehme! Right, the problem is non-convex. Any idea for a solver for non-convex qp?

Comment: Many thanks @JohanLöfberg! What I understood from your comment is that SDP cannot be a good choice unless I can use some specific structure of the model. Is that correct? If it is so then I should go back to MIQP. 
Just a general question: which one is easier to deal with, and is better to have on the article from the reader's point of view: MIQP or QCQP? 

MIQPs are at least solvable but it seems to me that a real world QCQP is not solvable at all. Right?

Comment: If the `z` variables are binary, then you have a MIP, with a quadratic objective function, not a quadratically constrained problem.  What do you mean by "z_i can be binary".

Comment: The QCQP as you have formulated it is very hard (as the relaxation of the constraint is non-convex since you have an equality). Any intelligent solver would however realize, as you have done, that it only involves squared terms (no bilinears) and thus can be written as a linear equality, collapsing the problem to a MIQP. For safety though, you might want to go explicitly to the MIQP form. As for a semidefinite relaxation, it does not scale well for general problems and is almost surely not useful.